# Mysql request returns undefined

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

So I am coding a program in node JS and I am using mysql.

I am sending a request to my DB and should return `"Null"` but each time I get `"undefined"` and i don't understand why. I saw some answers on stack overflow but I don't understand them.

Here is my function:

```
async function checkKey(key) {
    var activated = "";
    var sqlcheck = "SELECT activated from authentification where discord_key = ?";
    console.log("in function");
    await DB.query(sqlcheck, [key], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw (err);
        console.log("test");
        console.log(result[0].customerID);
        activated = result[0].customerID;
    });
    if (activated == "Null") {
        return ("NULL");
    } else {
        return ("used");
    }
}
```

`console.log(result[0].customerID);` returns `"undefined"`

I call it at this moment in another function :

```
if (checkKey(key) == "NULL") {
    try {
```

Is it possible to wait for the function `"checkkey"` to finish before continuing?

These are my logs :

```
logged in as ${client.user.tag}!
in function
${message.author.tag} - inputted an used key. key : ${key}
test
undefined
```

It should say :

```
logged in as 
in function 
test
undefined
${message.author.tag} - inputted an used key. key : ${key}
```

The main function continue to run without checking if the function ended.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> `if (activated == "Null")`

`NULL` is not a string, it is a special value in SQL language that indicates that the value is uknown, in other words undefined.

When your database driver retrieves a `NULL` value from database, it converts it into whatever corresponds to the `NULL` concept in the computer language that you are using, which in javascript would be an `undefined` variable.

You could simply rewrite this condition to a boolean check :

```
if (!activated)
```

This will catch the cases where `activated` is an empty string, an undefined value, a false boolean value, and the number `0`.

If you want to allow `0`, then :

```
if (activated !== 0)
```

Comment: hello,
So i did what you said, but I still get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerID' of undefined